# Check if form is changed in ext-gwt and highlight save button

Tags: gxt

this might be a simple question.
we have a form with different widgets, tables and etc.

in that form we need to highlight save button and enable/disable other action buttons
right after a user changed form data.

do you know about any elegant way to handle dirty forms
I like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dirtyform but this is not gxt.

Thank you, 
SLava

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FormBindings and BeanModel then just implement a changeListener to your BeanModel and do what you need to in that method.

For example:

```
myBean= BeanModelLookup.get().getFactory(MyBean.class)
            .createModel(myBean);
    myBean.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void modelChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            PropertyChangeEvent propertyEvent = (PropertyChangeEvent) event;
            if (!propertyEvent.getOldValue().toString().equals(
                    propertyEvent.getNewValue().toString())) {
                hasBeanChanged= true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi stan229,we don't use bean model, but the idea is clear. thank you!